# failed to push some refs to ... (heroku)

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to host a django website to heroku platform but i get this error, what should I do ?

```
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.10
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.9.10
remote: -----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to mighty-garden-63583.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mighty-garden-63583.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mighty-garden-63583.git'
```

Comment: Read the line `remote:        ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` (Note: this comes from heroku - Git's only involvement here is as a transport system.)

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: Side note: what are you using PyAudio for? You won't be able to access the end user's microphone or speakers since your Python code runs on the server, not the client.

Comment: Another side note: I see `Installing SQLite3` here. Not sure how your project is configured, but if you're actually using SQLite on Heroku [you're going to have problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heroku+sqlite).

Comment: I'm not using PyAudio at all

Comment: @SaadOL, is it in your `requirements.txt`? It could be a transitive dependency, but that would be unlikely to try using a Windows wheel. Did you generate your `requirements.txt` from an environment, or the other way around?

Comment: i didn't use a virtual environment for the project, I just create the procfile and the requirements inside the project folder where it contains manage.py & db.sqlite3 and the other files of django

Comment: _How_ did you create the requirements file? By doing something like `pip freeze > requirements.txt`?